# Why do I get 0x0000005D (UNSUPPORTED_PROCESSOR) in recent Windows versions?

Tags: windows-installation, windows-10-preview

So, I tried too install Windows Technical Preview, yes this referes too PAE/NX/SSE2 not working *but* I have these features. Anyidea what's going on here?

```
          Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
 x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
 Microcode signature: 00000005
 HTT        *   Hyperthreading enabled
 HYPERVISOR -   Hypervisor is present
 VMX        -   Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
 SVM        -   Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
 X64        *   Supports 64-bit mode

 SMX        -   Supports Intel trusted execution
 SKINIT     -   Supports AMD SKINIT

 NX         *   Supports no-execute page protection
 SMEP       -   Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
 SMAP       -   Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
 PAGE1GB    -   Supports 1 GB large pages
 PAE        *   Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
 PAT        *   Supports Page Attribute Table
 PSE        *   Supports 4 MB pages
 PSE36      *   Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
 PGE        *   Supports global bit in page tables
 SS         *   Supports bus snooping for cache operations
 VME        *   Supports Virtual-8086 mode
 RDWRFSGSBASE   -   Supports direct GS/FS base access

 FPU        *   Implements i387 floating point instructions
 MMX        *   Supports MMX instruction set
 MMXEXT     -   Implements AMD MMX extensions
 3DNOW      -   Supports 3DNow! instructions
 3DNOWEXT   -   Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
 SSE        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
 SSE2       *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
 SSE3       *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
 SSSE3      -   Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
 SSE4a      -   Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
 SSE4.1     -   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
 SSE4.2     -   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

 AES        -   Supports AES extensions
 AVX        -   Supports AVX intruction extensions
 FMA        -   Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
 MSR        *   Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
 MTRR       *   Supports Memory Type Range Registers
 XSAVE      -   Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
 OSXSAVE    -   Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
 RDRAND     -   Supports RDRAND instruction
 RDSEED     -   Supports RDSEED instruction

 CMOV       *   Supports CMOVcc instruction
 CLFSH      *   Supports CLFLUSH instruction
 CX8        *   Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
 CX16       *   Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
 BMI1       -   Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
 BMI2       -   Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
 ADX        -   Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
 DCA        -   Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
 F16C       -   Supports half-precision instruction
 FXSR       *   Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
 FFXSR      -   Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
 MONITOR    *   Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
 MOVBE      -   Supports MOVBE instruction
 ERMSB      -   Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
 PCLMULDQ   -   Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
 POPCNT     -   Supports POPCNT instruction
 LZCNT      -   Supports LZCNT instruction
 SEP        *   Supports fast system call instructions
 LAHF-SAHF  -   Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
 HLE        -   Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
 RTM        -   Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

 DE         *   Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
 DTES64     *   Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
 DS         *   Implements memory-resident debug buffer
 DS-CPL     *   Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
 PCID       -   Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
 INVPCID    -   Supports INVPCID instruction
 PDCM       -   Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
 RDTSCP     -   Supports RDTSCP instruction
 TSC        *   Supports RDTSC instruction
 TSC-DEADLINE   -   Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
 TSC-INVARIANT  -   TSC runs at constant rate
 xTPR       *   Supports disabling task priority messages

 EIST       *   Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
 ACPI       *   Implements MSR for power management
 TM         *   Implements thermal monitor circuitry
 TM2        -   Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
 APIC       *   Implements software-accessible local APIC
 x2APIC     -   Supports x2APIC

 CNXT-ID    *   L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

 MCE        *   Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
 MCA        *   Implements Machine Check Architecture
 PBE        *   Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

 PSN        -   Implements 96-bit processor serial number

 PREFETCHW  -   Supports PREFETCHW instruction

 Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 00000003 (Basic), 80000008 (Extended).

 Logical to Physical Processor Map:
 **  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)

 Logical Processor to Socket Map:
 **  Socket 0

 Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
 **  NUMA Node 0

 Logical Processor to Cache Map:
```

Comment: How much RAM you have?

Comment: Please write a little bit more detailed question. You didn't mentioned which version are you using. I guess 64-bit.

Answer (score 8):

You can only install the 32Bit Version because your CPU doesn't support [PREFETCHW](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PREFETCHW.html) (*  means supported and the **-** means NOT supported):

```
PREFETCHW - Supports PREFETCHW instruction
```

which is a requirement for installing the 64Bit Version since Windows 8.1

Comment: For those wondering, [Windows 8.1 system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) lists the requirements; the 32-bit requirements are given by the bold processor line, the additional 64-bit requirements are given by the line "To install a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit PC, your processor needs to support CMPXCHG16b, PrefetchW, and LAHF/SAHF". Besides what is suggested in this answer, the OP's processor appears to be missing support for LAHF-SAHF as well.

Comment: How to detect that? - Pointing to a specific ark.intel or amd page would suffice.

Comment: @mbx run CoreInfo on your current system: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx

Comment: Does anyone have an explanation for why it's required? From what I can gather it just offers a performance boost - so why can't Windows 8.1 just run a little bit slower?

Comment: @AaronFranke ask this Microsoft. They decided it so.