# Can I install Windows 10 home? Laptop processor configuration is Core 2 Due (T6500 @ 2.10 GHz, 2M Cache, 800 MHz FSB), RAM 4GB

Tags: windows-10, intel-core2

**I want to install windows 10 in my Old Laptop,** Processor is Core 2 Due (T6500 @ 2.10 GHz, 2M Cache, 800 MHz FSB), RAM 4 GB, Storage 300 GB. is it possible? how much speed or slow?

Comment: You can almost certainly run Windows 10 32-bit, but I think 64-bit may have some extra requirements on the CPU: https://superuser.com/questions/931742/windows-10-64-bit-requirements-does-my-cpu-support-cmpxchg16b-prefetchw-and-la As mentioned in the main answer there the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant should inform you if there are unmet requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that system exceeds the minimum specs for Windows 10. Of-course, your system is likely worth less then a Windows 10 license.

With regard to speed, "relative to what?". Its never going to be grea, but it will be usable. Light weight Linux distro will outperform Windows 10 by a good margin. It will be OK for light office work and browsing.

I would be concerned about a 300 gig disk. Its old, and likely to fail.  If the interface is SATA, replace it with an SSD. That will also improve Windows speed - especially on a ram-constrained system. The size of the disk is not that important to Windows - even a 250 gig will do fine unless you want to store lots of video/audio.