# Windows 10 22h2 Processor Compatibility

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu, compatibility

My employer has a number of PC that still run Windows 7 (let's not get into why...), it will be necessary for us to upgrade each of these PCs to Windows 10 22H2 very soon. If I reference Microsoft's "Windows 10 22H2 Supported Intel Processors" document at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-10-22h2-supported-intel-processors?source=recommendations

it does not list any of the processors I have in these PCs as supported. However, Windows Updates have been nice enough to update my PC to run Windows 10 22H2 and it has one of these processors in question (3.10 gigahertz Intel Core i5-2400). I have not experienced any issues, and this is my daily driver.

Management want to know how many of these PCs can be reused, and with none of the processors listed I am flummoxed...The old Windows 10 Advisor application doesn't appear to be available any longer from MS and the new version for Windows 11 requires it be run from Windows 10.

How can I determine the actual compatibility of processors with Windows 10 22H2? or is it a case of "It's not supported, but runs just fine"?

The processors I am dealing with are
Intel Core i7-3770
Intel Core i5-3470
AMD Athlon II X3 440
Intel Core i5-2500
Intel Core i5-2400
Intel Core i7-4790
Intel Core i7-2600
Intel Core i5 650
Intel Core i7 860
Intel Core i5-2300
Intel Core i7-2600S
Intel Xeon E5-1620 v3
Intel 11th Gen Core i7-11700
Intel 11th Gen Core i5-1135G7

Comment: It'll be necessary for y'all to upgrade everything to Windows 11, at least, very soon - support for Windows 10 ends next year - so better to plan ahead.

Comment: There is no way Core i5-2400 is supported by Windows 11, specifically in the context of, a system running with a Core i5-2400 would fail the processor compatibility check. I have a 4th generation core processor, which is close to a 2nd generation Core processor, and that system fails the processor compatibility check. [WhyNotWindows11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11) will tell you if a system is or isn't compatible with Windows 11. A system that is incompatible with Windows 11 can still run Windows 11 it will just fail the compatibility check via Windows Update.

Comment: Here is the point where I realize you are upgrading to Windows 10 not Windows 11.  When Windows 10 was released, the system requirements for Windows 7 and Windows 10 were identical, but there was a single additional x86 instruction requirement that was made back in 2016.  However, the require instruction at the time, was more a decade old.  All of your processors are newer than a decade or were released after 2006.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/931742/windows-10-64-bit-requirements-does-my-cpu-support-cmpxchg16b-prefetchw-and-la) is a question that explains which instruction that was back in 2015.  Best use [coreinfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo) yourself to determine if your processors support the required x86 instructions to run Windows 10.

Comment: Aren't there any third parties that report on Windows 10 compatibility with different processors? Ramhound: I assure you I am running 22H2 on an i5-2400, Windows 11 advisor does indicate that the processor isn't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

A CPU not found on the list does not means that Windows 10 won't work
on it. It only means that Microsoft hasn't run tests on computers
using that CPU.

The
[Windows 10 system requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-system-requirements-6d4e9a79-66bf-7950-467c-795cf0386715)
are fairly low and depend on more than just the CPU:

- Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster processor or SoC
- RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit
- Hard disk space: 16 GB for 32-bit OS or 20 GB for 64-bit OS
- Graphics card: DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver
- Display: 800 x 600

If all the computers fulfill these requirements, Windows 10 might
work on them.

The real problem would be to ensure that there exist Windows 10
drivers for all the components. Normally these drivers are to be
found in the website of the manufacturer of the motherboard.
Third-party drivers are to avoided.

Note that Windows 10 version 22H2 will reach
end of servicing on October 14, 2025.